# dragular "remove on spill" dosent work properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to figure out, how to set options in Dragular Service (http://luckylooke.github.io/dragular/#/home) to get desired behavior:
lets assume that we have two containers, `containerLeft` and `containerRight`.
We would like to be able to drag&drop *copied* items only from `containerLeft` to `containerRight`. Example: when we move item `left 1` to `containerRight` it should be visible in `containerLeft` and `containerRight`. That works fine. OK, we would like to have on more feature - remove items from `containerRight`. Below my controller code:

```
function TestController(dragularService, $element, $scope) {
    $scope.left = [
        {content: 'left 1'},
        {content: 'left 2'},
        {content: 'left 3'}
    ];

    $scope.right = [
        {content: 'right 1'},
        {content: 'right 2'},
        {content: 'right 3'}
    ];

    var containerLeft = document.querySelector("#containerLeft");
    var containerRight = document.querySelector("#containerRight");

    //remove items from containerRight dosent work properly  
    dragularService([containerRight], {
        removeOnSpill: true
    });

    dragularService([containerLeft, containerRight], {
        containersModel: [$scope.left, $scope.right],
        copy: true,
        //move only from left to right  
        accepts: function (el, target, source, sibling) {
            if (source === containerRight && target === containerLeft) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And view:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="TestController">
    <div class="column small-6">
        <div id="containerLeft" style="">
            <div ng-repeat="item in left">{{item.content}}</div>
        </div>
        <div id="containerRight" style="">
            <div ng-repeat="item in right">{{item.content}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column small-6">
        <pre>
            left: {{ left | json}}
        </pre>
        <pre>
            right: {{ right | json}}
        </pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I remove items from `containerRight` they disappear from view but they are still in `right` array (and if I drag&drop something from left to right, the removed earlier items appears again). Additionally, when I change the items order in `containerRight` it doesn't have impact on `right` array - items orderd dosen't change. How to set the `options` object to get it work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, setup is correct, its bug actually.. I have raised the issue [on project github page](https://github.com/luckylooke/dragular/issues/37), and I will fix it soon ;)

**EDIT**: Ok, setup was not correct, but there was also a bug, I have fixed it in dev branch, will be merged in next release.

Here is correct setup:

```
function TestController(dragularService, $element, $scope) {
    $scope.left = [{
      content: 'left 1'
    }, {
      content: 'left 2'
    }, {
      content: 'left 3'
    }];

    $scope.right = [{
      content: 'right 1'
    }, {
      content: 'right 2'
    }, {
      content: 'right 3'
    }];

    var containerLeft = document.querySelector("#containerLeft");
    var containerRight = document.querySelector("#containerRight");

    //remove items from containerRight dosent work properly  
    dragularService([containerRight], {
      containersModel: [$scope.right],
      removeOnSpill: true,
      nameSpace: 'sameSpace'
    });

    dragularService([containerLeft], {
      containersModel: [$scope.left],
      copy: true,
      //move only from left to right  
      accepts: function(el, target, source, sibling) {
        if (source === containerRight && target === containerLeft) {
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      },
      nameSpace: 'sameSpace'
    });
  }
```

Explanation:
You cannot call dragularService on same container more than once, if you want different options for containers, you must call dragularService on them separately and then connect them via nameSpace.

Comment: Thanks for your support

Comment: Youre welcome.. I will remove need of nameSpaces in future.. for now they must be there to be in same domain if containers are initialized separately.